# How to add the legend for hline in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data looks like this:

```
month=c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun")
rate=c(70,80,90,85,88,76) 
dd=data.frame(month,rate)
dd$type="Rate"
dd$month=factor(dd$month)
```

I tried to create the plot like this:

```
ggplot(dd,aes(x=month,y=rate,color=type)) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=month,y=rate, group=1), size=2) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(format(rate, digits = 4, format = "f"), "%")), 
            color="black",vjust = -0.5, size = 3.5) +
  geom_line(aes(x = month, y = rate, group=1), size=1) + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=85), linetype='dashed',colour="#F8766D", show.legend=T) +
  labs(y="", x="") + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#00BFC4")) +
  scale_fill_discrete(limits = c("Target")) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

As you can see, the legend of Rate and Target are overlapping together (there is red dash line in the green line), I'd like to know how to create the legend for Target and Rate in the correct way. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to map on aesthetics and make use of `scale_xxx_manual` instead of setting the color, linetypes, ... via arguments:

```r
month=c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun")
rate=c(70,80,90,85,88,76) 
dd=data.frame(month,rate)
dd$type="Rate"
dd$month=factor(dd$month)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dd,aes(x=month,y=rate, color="Rate", linetype = "Rate")) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=month,y=rate, shape = "Rate"), size=2) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(format(rate, digits = 4, format = "f"), "%")), 
            color="black",vjust = -0.5, size = 3.5) +
  geom_line(aes(x = month, y = rate, group=1, size = "Rate")) + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=85, color = "Target", linetype = "Target", size = "Target")) +
  labs(y = NULL, x= NULL, color = NULL, linetype = NULL, shape = NULL, size = NULL) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c(Rate = "#00BFC4", Target = "#F8766D")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(Rate = "solid", Target = "dashed")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(Rate = 16, Target = NA)) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(Rate = 1, Target = .5)) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]